# Mobile Network Problem

Tags: mobile-network

I am facing mobile network issue in my office only. When I enter in my office my mobile signal problem arises, Is it due to the router or some other electronic devices? And when I go out from my office I again got signal into my mobile what exactly the issue is. I am not getting.

Comment: Although I am voting to close this as off-topic (not Android dependent), this is common issue. Carriers use different frequencies and those radio frequencies penetrate structures differently. I guess the frequencies your carrier uses don't penetrate your office building very well. I think it is unlikely that your poor signal is caused by interference from some other device.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are facing signal loss when inside a building?

If so then that is normal. Indoor areas suffer from lower signal reception due to the having to pass through the walls. Whilst modern signal transmitters and phones are usually only marginally affected, all sorts of factors can affect this including how "deep" into a building you are, distance from transmitter, building materials etc.

If you are only facing this issue inside a particular room then perhaps the room is specially screened? You may also be in a signal dead-spot where you just have little signal.

Whilst WiFi and other common wireless systems are on frequencies that should not interfere with your phone signal, you may have some specialist kit in your office however this is very unlikely.

If you'd like to track your signal strength as you move between locations you can use the phone status option in settings.

Comment: Mobile network problem is coming from  last 20 days only. Previously there were no such problem inside the office. Problem is coming only when we are inside the Office now days.

Comment: How odd. No way that anyone could really know in that case. Perhaps your previous transmitter no longer works and you are using another one, or your network is having issues. Alternatively you could always ask your local IT team if they had any boosting equipment that no longer functions? At our office we have signal boosters and when they broke lots of people had reduced signal.  Either way, unless you have modified your phone, I don't think this is quite suitable for this S/E. Good luck!

Comment: The problem is not only with a single mobile. People have different mobile sets. Everybody is facing the same problem.
Which device can be the cause of this? Router,Computer,Laptop or something else?

Comment: There is no guarantee that it is a device interfering with signals. It could just be that your signal in that area is now worse due to a transmitter error. In the first instance I would try and contact the network provider and your local IT team to see if any local changes have occurred. This doesn't sound like something that can be solved on here. Best of luck.

Comment: Ok thanks, It means first i need to talk with my IT team and my network provider. Thanks budddy for your suggestion :)